# facebook feed url + or white space not accepted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am using facebook feed url as follows

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1580821915509011&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://www.xxxx.com/closewindow&name=test&link=http://www.xxxcom&picture=http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/processed/c2b88b7abc1256808c53cd7b7334d3d3/StreamPhotos/893115e2f8a68801c93cebaf103a6f8e.jpeg+&properties=&actions=
```

This works fine but when I have

```
picture=http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/processed/c2b88b7abc1256808c53cd7b7334d3d3/**Stream+Photos**/893115e2f8a68801c93cebaf103a6f8e.jpeg
```

or

```
picture=http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/processed/c2b88b7abc1256808c53cd7b7334d3d3/**Stream Photos**/893115e2f8a68801c93cebaf103a6f8e.jpeg
```

Facebook url doesnot fetch the images how to resolve this?

Comment: You'll probably have to encode the URL. No idea what language you're using, but in JS you can use `encodeURIComponent(string)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with the spaces-to-plusses encoding - but you need to URI-escape the string. You should end up with the spaces as `%20`. That'll be what Facebook is looking for!